# Combine Tables matching a name pattern in Power Query

Tags: powerquery, m

I am trying to combine many tables that has a name that matches a patterns.
So far, I have extracted the table names from #shared and have the table names in a list.

What I haven't being able to do is to loop this list and transform in a table list that can be combined.

e.g. Name is the list with the table names:

```
Source = Table.Combine( { List.Transform(Name, each #shared[_] )} )
```

The error is:

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]
```

I have tried many ways but I am missing some kind of type transformation.

I was able to transform this list of tables names to a list of tables with:

```
T1 = List.Transform(Name, each Expression.Evaluate(_, #shared))
```

However, the Expression.Evaluate feels like an ugly hack.  Is there a better way for this transformation?

With this list of tables, I tried to combine them with:

```
Source = Table.Combine(T1)
```

But I got the error:

```
Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.
```

If I extract the table from the list with the index (e.g T1{2}) it works.  So in this line of thinking, I would need some kind o loop to append.

Steps illustrating the problem.

1. The objective is to append (Tables.Combine) every table named T_\d+_Mov:
   [image: Existing Tables]
2. After filtering the matching table names in a table:
   [image: Tables Name Table]
3. Converted to a List:
   [image: Tables Name List]
4. Converted the names in the list to the real tables:
   [image: Tables List]
5. Now I just need to combine them, and this is where I am stuck.

It is important to not that I don't want to use VBA for this.
It is easier to recreate the query from VBA scanning the ThisWorkbook.Queries() but it would not be a clean reload when adding removing tables.

The final solution as suggested by @Michal Palko was:

```
CT1 = Table.FromList(T1, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Name"}, null, ExtraValues.Ignore),
EC1  = Table.ExpandTableColumn(CT1, "Name", Table.ColumnNames(CT1{0}[Name]) )
```

where T1 was the previous step.
The only caveat is that the first table must have all columns or they will be skiped.

Comment: Add some dummy data or screenshots

Comment: @Ben, done.  Probably there is a simpler way for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be easier way but given your approach try to convert your list to table (column) and then expand that column:

[image]

Alternatively use `Table.Combine(YourList)`

Comment: I need some help to get there.  I have the Tables in a List and not in a Table(row) [item 4].
I have no Idea how to convert this List to a Table.
Table.FromList() or List.Transform does not work ( or I am doing it wrong) .

Comment: and please, an easier/simpler way is more than welcome.
I am still struggling with M, it looks like a lot like sendmail's config.

Comment: Your approach with Table.FromList is ok, but requires more parameters. Easier way to do that is Right click on the list -> To Table. I edited answer for alternative solution using Table.Combine

Comment: The Table.Combine(List) generates: "Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation." error.

Comment: That helped!
The final solution was (I will edit the post):
    CT1 = Table.FromList(T1, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"Name"}, null, ExtraValues.Ignore),
    EC1  = Table.ExpandTableColumn(CT1, "Name", Table.ColumnNames(CT1{0}[Name]) )

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this question but needed extra help understanding the `#shared` bit. It's explained in more detail [here](https://radacad.com/power-query-library-of-functions-shared-keyword) but it's just a keyword in Power Query that returns a list of all the queries in the workspace.